# Saving Spark RDD as textFile with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage

I am using Spark 1.5 and want to save my RDD as textFile in Google Cloud Storage. Something like below.

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile("gs://bucket/file_name")
```

I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/google-cloud-storage-connector#getting) link. But this connector is for applications running inside Google Compute Engine. Is it possible to use this connector outside of Google Compute Engine?

I tried with the below settings, but it does not seem to be working. It fails with the authentication error. Are there any configurations I am missing.

```
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
conf.set("fs.gs.project.id", "celtra-bigquery-eval")
conf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "false")
conf.set("google.cloud.auth.client.file", "/mnt/credentials.json")
```

Please point me to some links or documents. Let me also know if you have other ways to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: You should post the text of the error you see. You should also be posting the information related to the context in which your code is running, not just that it *isn't* Compute Engine. With this information, people will be more likely to be able to recommend a fix.